# CSS: two side-by-side p tags, same height, left one fixed-width & known height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a vertical list of `<li>`'s of varying height, where each has two `<p>` tags next to each other and has a height of the tallest `<p>` tag; the `<p>` on the left has a fixed width (`128px`) and the `<p>` on the right should take up the rest of the page but *not* wrap underneath the first `<p>`.

Here's sample HTML:

```
<ul>

  <li> <!-- height = the tallest of the two p tags -->
    <p class="category">Something (128px wide)</p>
    <p class="description">Something long...
        Shouldn't wrap underneath .category
    </p>
  </li>

  <li> <!-- beneath the li above, probably different height -->
    <p class="category">Another thing</p>
    <p class="description">Another long description...</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

What should the CSS look like?

Comment: Could you do this in a table instead? It's exactly what tables are designed for. You could probably hack it together with CSS but unless there's a specific reason for using a UL you should use a table

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought of that, thanks! I hope it's alright - I've never used tables for layouts but this is a "categories"-in-the-left-column, "descriptions"-in-the-right-column thing, so I guess it's a good use-case for `<table>`?

Comment: Actually, that's entirely the opposite of what tables were designed for. They were created for tabular data, not layout. Using them for layout is the hack. Using CSS for layout is not a hack.

Comment: Weird, I didn't see your comment prior to my last one. Like I said elsewhere in comments, if it is tabular data, then absolutely. But, use a TR that contains TH tags at the top so that it is a proper table. If the data doesn't compel the use of the headers, then I would assert that you were on the right track with the list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to skin this cat. If I'm understanding what you're after correctly, I think that using table-row and table-cell display properties may be the easiest way to go.

Here's a jsfiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/s2jzh31z/2/

That includes the following,
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="category">Something (known width)</p>
    <p class="description">Something long and multiple lines.
        Shouldn't wrap underneath category. 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi. 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur adipiscing elit no numi.</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p class="category">Another thing(known width)</p>
    <p class="description">Something to the right,
      determines the height of this "&lt;li&gt;"</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    clear: both;
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .5em;
    vertical-align: top;
}

p.category {
    width: 128px;
}
```

I took the liberty of vertical aligning and adjusting the padding a bit to make it look neater. The vertical align was one of the benefits I was looking for in using the table-row / table-cell approach.

Comment: I didn't know about `display: table-row` or `-cell`. Thanks for that! I think I'll make the whole thing a `<table>` though :)

Comment: See my other comments. I highly recommend against using a table for layout. CSS was created to eliminate the need to hack layout with tags that have a different semantic meaning. You're welcome! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do the trick for you.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
li p {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
p.category {
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <!-- height = the tallest of the two p tags --->
    <p class="category">Something (known width)</p>
    <p class="description">Something long... Shouldn't wrap underneath .category
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <!-- beneath the li above, probably different height -->
    <p class="category">Another thing</p>
    <p class="description">Another long description...</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

More Info:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

To be semantically correct and 'new age' you could do this using CSS3's Flexbox layout but if this is table data (looks to be, using category and description) then you could restructure it as a table (which also helps if you need to support older browsers).
HTML would look like this:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Something (known width)</td>
        <td>Something long and multiple lines.sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddsdssdsssssssssssssssssssssssssss
            Shouldn't wrap underneath .category</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="category">Another (known width)</td>
        <td>Another long and multiple lines.
            Shouldn't wrap underneath .category</td>  </tr>

    </table>
```

and your CSS:

```
.category {
    width: 128px;
}
```

Comment: Tables should only be used for actual tabular data, not layout. HTML should be sematically correct. This is how it would have been done in the 90s.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. To me this looks like categorical data which I wouldn't call layout at all so this is correct.

Comment: If it is indeed tabular data, then yep. ADA requirements would be better met with a table when it comes to tabular data, however a reader would assist the visually impaired user better if the table had a table row (tr) at the top that contained table headings (th). Cheers

Comment: There should be a badge for having an accepted answer which is in negative votes lol